# Проблема с загрузкой изображений с локального сервера

Tags: php, mysql, openserver

Сделал сайт по выводу изображений на локальном сервере(OpenServer).Открываю главную страницу со всеми изображениями, потом открываю страницу ,с полным описание изображения, и изображение не выводится а в коде страницы в аргументе src - null. Потом это же изображение перестает открываться и на главной странице. Код главной страницы и страницы с описанием изображения приложу снизу.

Код по выводу изображений на главной странице

```
$sql_qestion = "SELECT * FROM Mangas  WHERE `src` != ''  LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0; ";
$kol = 9;  //количество записей для вывода
$art = ($page * $kol) - $kol; // определяем, с какой записи нам выводить
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `Mangas`  WHERE `src` != '' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $art,$kol"); 
$res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM Mangas WHERE `src` != ''");
$q = mysqli_query($link,$sql_qestion);
$total= mysqli_num_rows($res);
$str_pag = ceil($total / $kol);
$manga=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
do{
        $href="article.php?id=".$manga[id];
         ?>
        <div class="work">

        <a href="<?php echo $href ?>">
            <?php echo "<img src= '";
            if ($manga[src]!=""){
                echo $manga[unical_id];
            }
            else {
                echo "img/no_img.webp";
            };
            echo " ' class='media' alt='' ".'/>';
             ?>
                <div class="content_row" >
                <h4><?php echo $manga[title] ?></h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php

         }while ($manga = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); ?>
```

Код страницы по выводу изображения и его описания

```
<div class="article_container"> 
<div><img class="img_s" src="<?php echo $sql[unical_id] ?>"></div>
<div><h1 class="title_of_manga"><?php echo $sql["title"] ?></h1></div>
<div class="tags"><p ><?php echo $sql[tags] ?></p></div>
</div>
<a class="sun-flower-button" href='manga_reder.php?id=<?php echo $sql[id] ?>'><div>
Watch manga</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Вместо `do while` нужно использовать `while`.  У вас в цикле намешан вывод данных на экран. Так делать не хорошо. Также в цикле `if ($manga[src]!=""){`, его можно заменить на `if ($manga[src]) {`, к тому же условие избыточно т.к. sql запрос уже отсекает такую выборку. Ещё в коде у вас куча ошибок, но в комментарий не вмещаются. Ну и отвечая на ваш вопрос, не зная что такое `$sql` и чему оно у вас равно, не возможно ответить на ваш вопрос. Расставьте по коду `var_dump($переменная)` и посмотрите в каком месте данные не те, что должны быть.

Comment: Это могут быть проблемы с настройками Nginx ? Просто это начало происходить после некоторых правок в Nginx.conf. Потом я вернул все как было но все равно не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в Javascript. Он заменял scr на null.